# Delete Relationship between Contact and Marketing List CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, crm

can anyone tells me how I can retrieve a contact in relationship with the marketing list in crm 4.0 ?

Marketinglist ("blabla") --> Contact(Adam Meyer)

I will see if a contact with a specicic Guid is in a Marketing List.

Hope you unterstand me...

Answer (score 1):

Those relationships are stored in a hidden entity called `listmember`. However, you can't retrieve those records directly. You'll have to do a retrieve on the contact entity, join it to list member, and then filter it based on the `listid` of the marketing list. [Here's an example.](http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/crminogic/archive/2009/05/04/retrieve-marketing-list-members.aspx)

To remove someone (as you mentioned in the title), you'll need to execute a `RemoveMemberListRequest`. [The SDK has the details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb957490.aspx)